# Java LWJGL Getting poor FPS

Tags: java, performance, render, lwjgl, frame-rate

I am writing a top-down 2D game. I am using a 128x128px tileset and am offering four zoom levels, 128,64,32 and 16px. I am using slick-utils draw method on my images to render them, looping through a two dimensional FOR loop, and have added a 'render range' into the mix to ensure that only the necessary amount of tiles are being rendered for what is visible on screen. The lag clearly comes from the rendering process, and although I get a solid FPS at the highest zoom level, 128x128, it steadily declines to 10FPS at 16x16px. I am sure this is an efficiency of code problem, however as a novice I don't know where to begin tackling it.

All help appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
for(int x=xPos-1;x<=xPos+renderRange;x++){
    for(int y=yPos-1;y<=yPos+renderRange;y++){

        /**Render Terrain*/
        Image texture = getTerrainTexture(map.tiles[x][y]);
        texture.rotate(map.tiles[x][y].imageRotate);
        texture.draw(x*128,y*128);

        /**Render Objects*/
        if(map.tiles[x][y].object != 0){
            Image object = getObjectTexture(map.tiles[x][y]);
            object.draw(x*128,y*128);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...you should probably post some code if you want help with code

Comment: I will post code, but I was looking for more of a theory solution, the code would only demonstrate what I've written, that I am using a 2D for loop and calling the slick-utils draw method

Comment: Are all your textures individually loaded, even if they're the same for different tiles? That's possibly the issue. It's hard to know without seeing more code.

Comment: I load a sprite sheet, I just use the getSprite function of the SpriteSheet object which returns an Image. These objects are provided by SlickUtil

Comment: I should also point out that I still get frame rate drops when I render plain GL_QUADS with a single colour, although not quite as bad, it's definitely noticeable. I wonder if using glScalef is the appropriate method of dealing with multiple zoom levels

Comment: In the plain GL_QUADS case, do you render all quads in one glDrawArrays/glDrawElements call, or do you use one call per Quad? There is quite a bit of overhead per call, see http://origin-developer.nvidia.com/docs/IO/8230/BatchBatchBatch.pdf

Comment: I am drawing them separately, so I can see how that would impact performance. However I would still need be rendering using slick-utils draw method for my textures, although it might be worth looking into switching to using a glDrawArrays call and the implications in bindings textures there. However, I am still surprised that a 2d game with at the moment no gameplay, only map rendering, drawing out a 64*64 grid of 16px tiles can cause such a drop in performance!

Comment: Thank you for the article though, I shall have a read!

Comment: I have deduced that the performance issue is coming from the scale, as I can comfortably render the amount of tiles needed for a maximum zoom out, just not scale them down using glScalef. I am considering the possibility of creating a buffered image of the map once it's generated, as the main terrain would require little modification (If I need to make changes I can just call an update the the buffered image in the section that needs changing, for efficiency). The map however is quite large, I'd definitely have to divide it up into several images, would this work?

Answer (score 8):

You should use another rendering method. The rendering method you are using right now is called immediate rendering. Suffice it to say that it is slow. You should use another rendering method such as [display lists](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/displaylists/) (static geometry only) or [vertex buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object) (more difficult to learn but they are not static).